# OleDb exception 0x80040e14 when trying to perform INSERT INTO

Tags: c#, ms-access

I got this exception when I'm trying to perform the `INSERT INTO` command:

[image: The Exception Image is here]

This is my code:

```
private void AddQuiz_Button_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Connection when button is clicked 
    OleDbConnection myConnection = GetConnection(); 

    string myQuery = "INSERT INTO  QuestionBank (Question, Choice A, Choice B, Choice C, Choice D, Category, Correct Answer) VALUES ('" + AddQuiz_RichTextBox_Question.Text + "' , '" + OptionA_TextBox.Text + "' , '" + OptionB_TextBox.Text + "' , '" + OptionC_TextBox.Text + "' , '" + OptionD_TextBox.Text + "' , '" + AddQuiz_Category_Listbox.Text + "' , '" + AddQuiz_ListBox_Answer.Text + "')" ; //SQuery statement 

    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, myConnection);

    try
    {
        // Opening connection
        myConnection.Open(); 

        AddQuiz_Label_CheckConnection.Text = "Connection Successful";
        // Execute the query 
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

        MessageBox.Show("Question saved");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Exception in DBHandler" + ex); 
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close connection 
        myConnection.Close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: And also - your column names in your `INSERT INTO` statement contains spaces - so you **must** enclose them in double quotes: `INSERT INTO QuestionBank (Question, "Choice A", etc.)`

Answer (score 0):

I seen that 800xxxx message. In near all cases it means your project is running at the wrong bit size for the installed version of Access.

If you cpu setting is "Any", then you need to change the project settings to x86.

Give that a try.

So this setting:

[image]

And then in configuration manager - create a new setting for x86

[image]

So new config, and then:

Change dropdown to x86 - and yes, you can accept the default "Copy settings from"

You now have this:

[image]

Then close button - and you now have this:

[image]

And of course the reverse is also true - if you running office x64, then force the project to x64 and again do not use "any".

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is caused by the *spaces* in your field names. Such names must, in Access SQL, be bracketed:

```cs
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO  QuestionBank (Question, [Choice A], [Choice B], [Choice C], [Choice D], Category, [Correct Answer]) VALUES ('" + AddQuiz_RichTextBox_Question.Text + "' , '" + OptionA_TextBox.Text + "' , '" + OptionB_TextBox.Text + "' , '" + OptionC_TextBox.Text + "' , '" + OptionD_TextBox.Text + "' , '" + AddQuiz_Category_Listbox.Text + "' , '" + AddQuiz_ListBox_Answer.Text + "')" ; //SQuery statement
```

That said, do learn to use *parameters* - much cleaner and easier to debug.